# Homestead - Connecting to my database

Tags: mysql, laravel, homestead

I just created a fresh laravel project and I'm using a Homestead vagrant box by running

> vagrant init laravel/homestead

and  after

> Vagrant Up

When I use `vagrant ssh` it gives me no problem and I can acces the vagrant box, however when I want to connect to the DB with Heidisql I get a connection error:

> can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)

Here's my setup

[image]
[image]

the password I'm using = "secret"

Answer (score 30):

The usual credentials/info you need:

- IP address 192.168.10.10 (Check your Homestead Folder>Homestead.yaml)
- Port: 3306
- User: homestead (all lowercase)
- Pw: secret

Comment: Took me ages to solve this when the Laravel docs specifically tell you to use 127.0.0.1 on port 33060

Comment: When using most recent versions, use IP 192.168.56.56 on port 3306

Answer (score 15):

You should be using the port 33060 instead of 3306 according to the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#connecting-to-databases).

The .env file should also be updated accordingly, so you won't have issues when running your first migration, as the Laravel installation is running inside the virtual machine you need the default port 3306 there.

Comment: In recent updates the IP has been changed to `192.168.56.56`

Answer (score 4):

The [MySQL official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) shows

> The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061)
>   indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should
>   check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network
>   connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the
>   one configured on the server.

You are trying to access to a MySQL server in another machine, with a virtual IP. I will use my IP's so you can understand better.

My host machine has 2 IP:

- the real IP is 192.168.0.53
- the virtual IP is 192.168.10.1

You can see your host machine IP's executing in a Windows machine

```
ipconfig
```

and in a Unix machine

```
ifconfig
```

You have to login to the Vagrant machine using

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then you have to execute

```
ifconfig
```

to see the IP's of the virtual machine.

In my Vagrant VM the IP are:

- 10.0.2.15
- 192.168.10.10

You can see that I have one IP in the host machine (192.168.10.1) and one in the Vagrant VM (192.168.10.10) in the same LAN.

The Vagrant VM IP (192.168.10.10 in my example) is the one you have to use in your MySQL client.

Answer (score 4):

The Homestead documentation says that you should use address 127.0.0.1 port 33060 to connect. I made a test and it worked.

> A homestead database is configured for both MySQL and PostgreSQL out of the box. To connect to your MySQL or PostgreSQL database from your host machine's database client, you should connect to 127.0.0.1 and port 33060 (MySQL) or 54320 (PostgreSQL). The username and password for both databases is homestead / secret.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#configuring-homestead

Answer (score 2):

#### First tab (Instelligen):

- IP Address: the IP that you defined in the `Homestead.yaml` file (mine is: 192.168.10.10)
- Username: homestead
- Password: secret

#### Second tab (SSH):

- IP Address - same as on the first tab
- Username: vagrant
- Password: vagrant

Leave everything else the same. This worked for me. I'm using the same HeidiSQL program.

Answer (score 0):

[Official Doc][1]

[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#connecting-to-databases is instructed to use port `33060` for MySQL and `54320` for PostgreSQL

> A homestead database is configured for both MySQL and PostgreSQL out of the box. To connect to your MySQL or PostgreSQL database from your host machine's database client, you should connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 33060 (MySQL) or 54320 (PostgreSQL). The username and password for both databases is homestead / secret.