# Connecting homestead laravel with mysql database

Tags: php, git, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Hi guys i'm a newbie having this problem and i can't find any aswer or anyone talking about this

[image]

as you can see after i enter the correct password to connect with the database nothing happens, the git bash cli remains like this i can type anything and it will remain the same, i have to do ctrl+c and "vagrant ssh" again because it gets stucked, thanks for the help

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try username `homestead`, password `secret`

Comment: also, if you want to list databases name, once your logged in your need to run SHOW Databases; which will list out all databases. if you want to see that database name you need to put that database name in homestead.yaml

Comment: My .env and database.php files are configurated with username homestead and password secret

Comment: @ankitpatel my homestead.yaml files already have the database name on it

Comment: yeah so that's why you need to run mysql -u homestead -p and than when prompt asked for password you need to enter 'secret'

Comment: @ankitpatel, i just tried typing mysql -u homestead -p and i'm having the same problem

Comment: [plz see the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643837/homestead-connecting-to-my-database)
hope this can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I once had this issue. Login to your phpmyadmin. Create a new username and password. Make these changes in your .env file. It should work.